# Command Prompt/Batch - How to implement If/Else statements using 3rd party commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface, command-prompt, mediainfo

Lets say I want to create a batch file. I work with video files and I use this well known tool MediaInfo. And it has a CLI version on Windows.

Lets say I want to rename bunch of files in a folder. So I run this:

```
for /r %%i in (*.mkv) do call ren "%%i" "renamed_files.mkv"
```

So what it does is that it picks up all `.mkv` files in the dir and renames it. That's great.

But what if I want to rename only specific `.mkv` files and not all of them? E.g. I have multiple `.mkv` files that has audio and some that doesn't. And lets say I want to rename only those that have audio. So to do that, I need to use some solution to scan/detect which files has audio. And to do that I thought why not use MediaInfo CLI. So we run this command:

```
mediainfo --inform="Audio;%ID%" file.mkv
```

And all it does, it prints `2` which is the ID of the audio track, which we could use to confirm that audio exists and the `.mkv` file should be picked up for renaming. And if there is no audio, it prints nothing, empty line, so those files should be skipped.

Makes sense and all, but I can't figure out how to wrap it up in `if` statements and make it work since its all new to me, I've been learning command prompt and batch files for 2 days now.

Or maybe someone knows even better solution. Except I'm not interested on installing 3rd party software with GUIs for that.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for /r %%i in (*.mkv) do (
  for /f "usebackq" in %%a (´mediainfo --inform="Audio;%ID%" file.mkv´) do set "audio=%%a"
  if defined audio (
    call ren "%%i" "renamed_files.mkv"
  )
)
```

the second `for` loop executes the command in parens and sets the `audio` variable to whatever the command returns. if it returns nothing, then the `audio` variable will be undefined and, in this case, the `if` block won't be executed.

Comment: As in OPs question the call is superfluous. You should initialize audio to prevent using remnants from previous iterations.

Comment: Why are you setting `%audio%`, just use `if not "%%a"=="" ren "%%i…`. In addition I'm not sure that renaming each and every file containing audio to the same name is a particularly good idea, nor does there seem any logic in using `call`, _(I know the OP did this too)._

Comment: hmm I don't what's wrong but .bat won't even run, it just blinks.